# Sql in Drupal 7 Tpl file

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

Can any one suggest me how to write SQL query in  .tpl file?

I tried to write db_query("select * from table_name "); But it is not working.

Please give me a solution to write sql query in tpl file

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below code and getting the records

```
$result = db_query("SELECT * from node");
$records = $result->fetchAll();
print_r($records);
```

Can you check the tpl file is correct or not, OR can you share the code.

Better to write a function in your module and return the data from the query to the tpl file.

```
 // function inside your module
    function your_custom_function(){
        $result = db_query("SELECT * from node");
        $records = $result->fetchAll();
        retun $records;
    }
```

Then you can call this function from tpl file

```
// calling the function from tpl    
$data = your_custom_function();
foreach($data as $value){
   // do your template logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.tpl files are for the template layout and should not have much more logic than if a region has content. For anything requiring more logic I'd recommend either adding an applicable hook in your template.php or look into creating your own module.

What is the goal you are trying to achieve it may be solvable in another way instead of using a custom query. Likely you can create a view for your page?

Otherwise, try testing your query first through your database - if you have phpmyadmin or similar set up to see if it is actually returning a result.

And see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7 for more information on how to use that particular function.